# Why should you care? / Why you should care?

Tags: idiomatic-language, word-order

A: What about you? Why should I care?

B: **Why should you care?** / **Why you should care?** You don't have to.

Are both word orders possible and natural or is only one correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion

Comment: *Why you should care* is not a valid utterance in your cited context. In other contexts, it's valid, but note that it's *just a **noun phrase**, not an actual **question*** (so it might appear as a chapter title in a book, or as the syntactic "object" in, say, *I don't know **why you should care***).

Answer (score 2):

As commented and already answered, in a question form, we should say

> Why should you care?

[Cambridge Dictionary]
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions) explains further.

> We usually form wh-questions with wh- + an auxiliary verb (be, do or have) + subject + main verb or with **wh- + a modal verb + subject + main verb** [emphasis added].

In your example, in forming the question, the modal verb *should* goes through an inversion with the subject *you*.

Answer (score -2):

Why   care?

Tell me why   care.

I know why   care.

Comment: This doesn't explain the use or difference at all.